# Локализация результата date() в opencart, PHP

Tags: php, opencart

Уважаемые программисты, кто может помочь с руссификацией данных "Месяц" в модуле Блог в Opencart 3? Код в controller PHP приходит на латинице:

```
foreach ($results as $result) {
    $data['articles'][] = array(
        'article_id'  => $result['article_id'],
        'name'        => $result['name'],
        'author'      => $result['author'],
        'image'       => $this->model_tool_image->resize($result['image'], $setting['width'], $setting['height']),
        'date_added'  => date($this->language->get('date_format_short'), strtotime($result['date_added'])),
        'date_added_m'  => date("M", strtotime($result['date_added'])),
        'date_added_d'  => date("d", strtotime($result['date_added'])),
        'date_added_y'  => date("Y", strtotime($result['date_added'])),
        'intro_text' => html_entity_decode($result['intro_text'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'),
        'href'        => $this->url->link('blog/article', 'article_id=' . $result['article_id'])
    );
}
```

Comment: Универсальный вариант - это сделать замену по словарю (ключ => значение). Т.е. создать массив англ. название => русские названия и пройтись каким-нибудь `str_replace`

Comment: @ArchDemon сможете оказать конкретную помощь в реализации?

Comment: - Джек, что ты можешь сделать за деньги?
- За деньги я могу сделать… всё

Answer (score 0):

config.php:

```
define ('MONTHS_TRANSLATES', [
    'jan' => [
        '0' => 'январь', // тут индексы это айди языков магазина
        '1' => 'january',
        '2' => 'styczeń'
        ],
    'feb' => [
        ...
    ],
    ...
]);
```

В далёком-далёком форыче, где-то в глубинах контроллера:

```
...
date_added_m => MONTHS_TRANSLATES[strtolower(date("M", strtotime($result['date_added'])))][$config_language_id];
...
```

[тыц](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/e5d71f3659fec119a3b033b2086f9715e879212f)

Comment: И ничего, что в config.php вставлить такой код? И на PHP 5.6 сработает? Точно?!

Comment: зачем же 5.6? если версия магазина >= 2.x (в 2020 году яхз кто ставит 1.х), то надо юзать любые доступные плюшки 7.х. На 5.6, естессно, не отработает, и вам придётся таскать этот массив по всем методам, где есть необходимость локализации месяцев.

Comment: 5.6.... 2020.... прям вот злюсь!!!

Comment: ошибки покажите? может тема не под вашу версию магазина?

Comment: есть как посмотреть? сайт локально или есть в инете?